# Has a list an item compared by reference?

Tags: c#

I have a list with 1000000 items and I need to figure out if a item is inside but by reference. Therefore I can't use `Contains` since `Contains` doesn't always match by reference (e.g. when list of type `string`). I tried `list.Any(x => object.ReferenceEquals)` but that is too slow.

Take a look here:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
  if(does list contains this item anotherList[i])
  {
    list.Add(anotherList[i]);
  }
}
```

How do I perform this really fast?

Comment: Clearly your list is too big.  Make it fast by also storing the objects in the list in a HashSet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary with an IdendityEqualityComparer to get the key comparison in the dictionary to do a reference comparison. The main difference between this approach and yours is that you have an O(1) lookup, instead of an O(n) lookup that you get from having to go through an entire list for each item.

Put the following code inside a sample Console app project; it basically splits a master dictionary into two.

```
public class IdentityEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T> where T : class
{
    public int GetHashCode(T value)
    {
        return RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(value);
    }

    public bool Equals(T left, T right)
    {
        return left == right; // Reference identity comparison
    }
}

public class RefKeyType
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var refDictionary = new Dictionary<RefKeyType, int>(1000000, new IdentityEqualityComparer<RefKeyType>());

        var testDictionary = new Dictionary<RefKeyType, int>(1000000, new IdentityEqualityComparer<RefKeyType>());

        var store = new Dictionary<RefKeyType, int>(1000000);

        for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            var key = new RefKeyType() {ID = i};

            refDictionary[key] = i;

            //Load the test dictionary if I is divisible by 2
            if (i%2 == 0)
            {
                testDictionary[key] = i;
            }
        }

        foreach (var key in refDictionary.Keys)
        {
            int val;
            if (!testDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out val))
            {
                store[key] = val;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Master dictionary has " + refDictionary.Count);
        Console.WriteLine("Test dictionary has " + testDictionary.Count);
        Console.WriteLine("Store dictionary has " + store.Count);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```